# Next.JS site doesn't run in localhost

Tags: npm, next.js, localhost, yarnpkg

Problem 1: When I try Yarn run dev, then it throws this error in the terminal:

$ next dev  Done in 8.44s.  but not run localhost [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfCkX.png)

problem 2: Then when I try with Yarn start, it gives me another error:

$ next start
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ammar\Desktop\Next\nextapp\my-next-app.next\BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\ammar\Desktop\Next\nextapp\my-next-app\.next\BUILD_ID'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Can anyone give me advice on how to fix this problem?